# Problem when import vector data from GRASS GIS within RStudio

Tags: r, grass-gis, vector, import, plot

I am trying to use `GRASS GIS 7.6` within `RStudio` and import a polygon which is in WGS 84 (EPSG 4326). I have created successfully the `location` and the `mapset` in `GRASS GIS`. When I use the command `v.import` from `RStudio` and plot the `shapefile` I'm getting the image bellow.
[image]
While I had to see something like this:
[image]
The code I used so far is:

```
setwd("my_dir")

library(rgrass7)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(stars)

use_sf()

initGRASS(gisBase = "where GRASS GIS folder is",
          gisDbase = "where my data are",
          location = "spain2", 
          mapset = "spain2",
          override = TRUE)

spain = execGRASS("v.import", flags = c ("overwrite", "o"), input = "spain.shp")

plot(spain)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rgrass7 function execGRASS does not return an R object that you can plot. It returns the success or failure of running the function. When you run "v.import" then you are importing the shapefile into the GRASS database,

What you might want is the function readVECT(). 
Here's an example:

```
library(rgrass7)
library(sf)

# Get Spain boundary from GADM
spain_file = "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/shp/gadm36_ESP_shp.zip"
spain_zip = download.file(spain_file, "spain.zip")
spain_shp = unzip("spain.zip")

# WHich file?
spain_shp[[4]]
initGRASS(gisBase = "/usr/lib/grass78/",
          gisDbase = file.path("/home/micha","GIS","grass"),
          location = "WGS84",
          mapset = "PERMANENT",
          override = TRUE)
execGRASS(cmd = "v.import",
        parameters = list(input = spain_shp[[4]],
                     output="gadm_ESP_0"),
        flags = c("overwrite"))
execGRASS(cmd = "v.info",
          map = "gadm_ESP_0")

# Move the GRASS vector over to R as an sf object
use_sf()
spain = readVECT("gadm_ESP_0")
class(spain)
str(spain)
# Plot the vector 
plot(spain$geom)
```

Although it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. If you want the spain shapefile in R, why not just run read_sf()??

Comment: Dear @Micha, thank you for your help. Your code does not working but it helped me to solve my initial problem. Here is what I 've changed in my code based on your suggestion:

`# Move the GRASS vector over to R as an sf object
use_sf()
spain = readVECT("spain")
class(spain)
str(spain)
 
plot(spain$geom)`
I just want to learn how to use `GRASS GIS`'s commands within `R`.

Comment: I edited my answer, and it should work now. (Note that the path to the grass directory gisBase must be set correctly for your installation). If you want more information regarding GRASS - R interaction, I suggest to start with [the GRASS wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics/rgrass7)